# Bolts.framework - Runs on iPhone 6 but not on iPod touch

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, parse-platform, ipod-touch

I'm making an iOS app that uses push notifications through the Parse SDK (installed using CocoaPods) and for testing I'm using three devices: an iPhone 6, an iPad Air 2 and an iPod touch (5th gen). The app runs with no trouble on the iPhone and the iPad.

While launching on the iPod, however, it crashes outputting the following error:

```
 dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Bolts.framework/Bolts
  Referenced from: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/3436C523-8F1F-445B-8099-435F7554DC96/[app name].app/[app name]
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/3436C523-8F1F-445B-8099-435F7554DC96/Monepp.app/Frameworks/Bolts.framework/Bolts: mach-o, but wrong architecture
    /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/3436C523-8F1F-445B-8099-435F7554DC96/Monepp.app/Frameworks/Bolts.framework/Bolts: mach-o, but wrong architecture
    /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/3436C523-8F1F-445B-8099-435F7554DC96/Monepp.app/Frameworks/Bolts.framework/Bolts: mach-o, but wrong architecture
```

I'm aware that the iPod uses a different architecture than the other two (32-bit instead of 64-bit), but the app also runs normally using an iPhone 4s simulator, which should use the same architecture as the iPod.

I've tried cleaning, checking the target architectures of the framework, re-installing the framework and installing a different version of the framework, but nothing helped.

What's also curious is that a few months ago I made an app in Objective-C using Parse that ran normally on the iPod. Any ideas?

UPDATE: Ever since updating to iOS 9, the error has no longer occurred.